# EF6 code first add-migration creates unusual migration but application runs

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 in VS2015 and have many, many successful migrations as I have been developing - until now.
I made a change to a table to specify the foreign key and ran add-migration.  I was surprised to see that not only was the change I expected there but many existing tables that have a string field are also being modified.

I reversed the changes to the foreign key but the string field changes are still being included in the migration.  The application runs OK so the database and model appear to be in sync but this strange migration still exists.

The tables being changed are all based on the following interface and class:

```
public interface IModificationHistory
{
    DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class ModificationHistory : IModificationHistory
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Display(Name = "Date modified")]
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [Display(Name = "Date created")]
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(256)]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

An example is

```
public class Organisation : ModificationHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(10)]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now the new migration suddenly wants to change the string length and is ignoring the MaxLength(256) attribute.  This occurs in all tables that have this inheritance specified.

It looks like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        //snip
        AlterColumn("dbo.Organisation", "UserName", c => c.String());
        //snip
    }
```

I am at a loss as to what has caused this or how to find how to stop the migration making this strange change - any clues?

**More interesting information.**

I updated the database with the strange migration and then found that there was a model error and the app would not run.  I had to remove the MaxLength attribute from the Username field and then all was OK.

Adding the attribute back on and fiddling with the MaxLength did not produce a new migration with anything in it - it seems that the attribute is being ignored but only where the table is inherited from this class.

Obviously I have changed something to make this happen but doing a commit to Git and having a good look at the files changed still gave me no clue.

Comment: And what does it generate in `Down` method?

Comment: It puts the length restriction back on again :  AlterColumn("dbo.Organisation", "UserName", c => c.String(maxLength: 256));

Comment: That's definitely strange and cannot be reproduced with clean test. Any special code not shown here - like `OnModelCreating` doing common fluent configuration based on interface etc. There must be something else causing it.

Comment: There are a couple of conventions being removed in OnModelCreating but they have not changed for months.

Answer (score 0):

[MaxLengthAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have `[AttributeUsage (Inherited = True)]` annotation, so it is ignored at inherited classes, as you suggested. At this case you should repeat `MaxLength` constraint with the help of Fluent API, something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types()
     .Where(x => typeof(ModificationHistory) != x && typeof(ModificationHistory).IsAssignableFrom(x))
     .Configure(x => x.Property("UserName").HasMaxLength(256));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Strange that this only just started happening and I have made dozens of migrations whilst developing this database. Still, if this fixes it I will be very thankful.